# Append data in datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Is there any solution i can append data to one datatable.

Example i have for loop which execute "Select " query on database. I store the result in a datatable. On second loop i will execute "Select " query once again but this time i will get different results. Is there any way i can store all those data into one datatable without loosing the data from previous loop

Dummy example

```
    For i = 0 To 10
        _cmd.CommandText = _sQ ' With different parameter in this query
        _da.SelectCommand = _cmd
        _da.Fill(_dt)
    Next
```

At the end my _dt should contain all data from this 10 iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataAdapter.Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx) method will append rows to the `DataTable` automatically:

> You can use the `Fill` method multiple times on the same `DataTable`. If a
>   primary key exists, incoming rows are merged with matching rows that
>   already exist. If no primary key exists, incoming rows are appended to
>   the `DataTable`.

So your code does already what you want:

```
For i = 0 To 10
    _cmd.CommandText = _sQ ' With different parameter in this query
    _da.SelectCommand = _cmd
    _da.Fill(_dt)
Next
```

As long as you don't specify the primary-key column(s) yourself you are not in "danger" of updates. All rows are appended to the table. I've tested it.

Answer (score 1):

If I know I only had one row in the results I probably wouldn't fill a datatable each time, but to answer your question you can keep one datatable reference as the main table and merge a table into it on each iteration:

```
Dim mainDT As New DataTable()
For i = 0 To 10
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    _cmd.CommandText = _sQ ' With different parameter in this query
    _da.SelectCommand = _cmd
    _da.Fill(dt)
    mainDT.Merge(dt)
Next
```

Comment: Actually nobody said it would be one row. Sometimes it would be around 200 rows sometimes 0.

Comment: @myString, my bad, I read "all data from this 10 iterations" as meaning 10 rows. You are right.

Comment: @Crowcoder: No need to merge tables, `DataAdaper.Fill` does already append rows to an existing table by default.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, so it does. Why then does OP experience loss of data? Maybe primary keys are clashing?

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic list for result and add new result item for each result.

Later you can just go trough list

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here by far is to eliminate the loop and modify your sql to handle all of the queries in one step. There are two ways to do this. The first and better method is to analyze your 10 SQL statements and get them down to one statement.

The second method is less effective but easier. Just concatenate your SQL commands into a `UNION` query:

```
Dim mainDT As New DataTable()
For i = 0 To 10
    _cmd.CommandText = _cmd.CommandText & " UNION & " & _sQ ' With different parameter in this query
Next
_da.SelectCommand = _cmd
_da.Fill(mainDT)
```